# How many ways can 2 rooks and a bishop be placed on a 4x4 board such that no piece attacks another piece?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

> How many ways can $2$ rooks and a bishop be placed on a $4\times 4$ board such that no piece attacks another piece?

I stumbled upon this question and I don't know how to find the answer mathematically. I wrote [this piece of code](https://pastebin.com/5J8fFSvh) to find the answer to it. I think the code is right, but I get the answer as $232$, which doesn't "feel" right. So how do you actually go about solving this question?

Comment: "*Such that no two pieces attack each other*"  This needs to be clarified.  If I have a rook at A1 and a bishop at A2, the rook is able to attack the bishop but the bishop may not attack the rook.  They are not both attacking the other... only the rook is attacking the bishop.  Do you mean instead "*Such that no piece attacks another pieces*"?

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry for the ambiguity, I meant no piece should attack another piece. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Well, seeing as the board is $4\times 4$, I'm actually surprised thet the number of positions should be so high.

Comment: @Gae.S. the number of ways of placing two rooks and a bishop is $\binom{16}{2}\times 14 = 1680$.  Only $13\%$ sounds about right to me.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm not questioning the correctness of the number: I'm just saying that the board is small and it's rather busy with two rooks already.

Comment: Hmm. There are 72 ways of placing the rooks (any pair of files, $\binom 42$,  four choices on the left files, three on the other). That leaves four possible squares for the bishop. A maximum of $288$. On a number of them the bishop will attack one of the rooks (if not both). $232$ is not outright impossible, but feels higher than I expected.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I looked at the code real hard, and I can't find the bug. So I wanted to confirm it here and learn the proper solution. Unfortunately I suck at programming :(

Comment: Some arrangements of rooks leave only a single possible square for the bishop. Some leave three. I would expect an average of about two, so an answer close to $144$. But I may have missed something. It does feel like brute force may be the fastest way :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Some arrangements leave _no_ squares for the bishop (e.g. rooks at `a1` and `c3`). And in fact the average is $29/18=1.6111\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force.

**Observation :** *The bishop can be treated as a queen*! We place Q first, then two identical rooks R1, R2.

There are three kinds of squares : corner (4), edge (8), center (4). We place first Q on each type and then two rooks.

*Center :* Q clears a $3\times 3$ grid and one more corner and two edge squares. Only four squares remain. Total $:4\cdot 2\cdot 2=16$ ways.

*Corner :* Q clears two edges and one diagonal. Six squares remain. Choosing any one of these six for R1 leaves three squares out for R2. Total $:(4\cdot 6\cdot 3)/2=36$

*Edge :*  Q clears an edge and a row/column and three more on its two diagonals. Six squares remain. If R1 is anywhere on one of three squares of an outer edge, it gives $2$ choices each for R2. Other three squares are at a knight's distance from Q. R1 on lonely square leaves 4 choices for R2. R1 on other pair of squres leaves $3$ choices each for R2. Total $$8\times \frac{3\cdot 2+4+2\cdot 3}{2}=64$$

Grand total $: 16+36+64=116$

Comment: Nice way of using the fact that the dihedral group has only three orbits on the 4x4.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Taking the bishop as a queen was clever!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Basic code (17 lines, including comments). It prints $116$, so it looks like you are treating the two rooks as different.

```
Private R1X, R1Y, R2X, R2Y, BX, BY
Private Counter = 0

For R1X = 1 To 3 : For R2X = R1X + 1 To 4
  For R1Y = 1 To 4 : For R2Y = 1 To 4
    If R2Y <> R1Y Then
      For BX = 1 To 4 : For BY = 1 To 4
        If BX <> R1X And BX <> R2X And BY <> R1Y And BY <> R2Y Then
          Rem  A bishop at (BX,BY) attacks a piece at (X,Y) if
          Rem  Abs(BX-X) = Abs(BY-Y):
          If Abs(BX - R1X) <> Abs(BY - R1Y) And Abs(BX - R2X) <> Abs(BY - R2Y) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
          End If
        End If
      Next BX, BY
    End If
Next R1X, R1Y, R2X, R2Y

Print Counter
```

Comment: Can you explain what treating the rooks as different means? I don't get what mistake I made exactly. [EDIT] Now I realised it! So I was double counting the rooks since both rooks should be the same, and hence I should've divided by 2. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a Mathematica snippet counting the number. My code also has, say, a black rook and a white rook. It gave 232 as the answer. So confirming Tony's result as well as yours @BrainNuke. My comment under main was based on two indistuingishable rooks, explaining why I felt that 232 is too high. Upvoting accordingly :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to solve the problem without a good deal of brute force.  It's pretty easy to calculate the number of ways to place two rooks that don't attack each other (You can choose the two rows in $4\choose2$ ways and the columns associated with them in another $4\cdot 3$), but then analyzing how to add a bishop would require at least some subcases and probably quite a lot.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was thinking about the rooks not attacking each other, but you are right that they would both be attacking the bishop.  I will take out the second paragraph.

Comment: It's kinda sad that only a brute force approach exists :(

Comment: @BrainNuke Yeah.  Martin Gardner wrote some articles about chessboard combinatorics problems for Scientific American way back in the day.  Most of the more interesting problems turned out to require enumeration more than formulas, alas.  Even so, devising a strategy for making sure that you don't double-count and don't miss any cases still counts as combinatorics!